How can VS Code run a script in the background repeatedly withoout my knowlege and strving me of processes?
VSC.  : Version: 1.90.0
MACOS : 14.5 (23F79)
Docker: version 26.1.3, build b72abbb6f0
colima: version 0.6.9

Hi all,
I was working on a bash script in VSC when I ran out of processes. After running out of processes, I had a look at what caused the problem. It turns out that VSC was spawning a docker container and replacing the user ($1) with '--help'. It then took it upon itself to spawn over 5k processes until it reached the user process limit. Stopping VS code released +5k processes and all was ok again.
This is what I could trace.
1200 84300 84236   0 11:16AM ??         0:19.64 /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) --type=utility --utility-sub-type=node.mojom.NodeService --lang=en-GB --service-sandbox-type=none --dns-result-order=ipv4first --inspect-port=0 --user-data-dir=/Users/someuser/Library/Application Support/Code --standard-schemes=vscode-webview,vscode-file --enable-sandbox --secure-schemes=vscode-webview,vscode-file --cors-schemes=vscode-webview,vscode-file --fetch-schemes=vscode-webview,vscode-file --service-worker-schemes=vscode-webview --code-cache-schemes=vscode-webview,vscode-file --shared-files --field-trial-handle=1718379636,r,6485740909175297229,8092115224772834401,262144 --enable-features=ScreenCaptureKitPickerScreen,ScreenCaptureKitStreamPickerSonoma,kWebSQLAccess --disable-features=CalculateNativeWinOcclusion,SpareRendererForSitePerProcess --variations-seed-version

1200 84303 84300   0 11:16AM ??         0:14.60 /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Frameworks/Code Helper (Plugin).app/Contents/MacOS/Code Helper (Plugin) /Users/someuser/.vscode/extensions/mads-hartmann.bash-ide-vscode-1.41.0/out/server.js --node-ipc --clientProcessId=84300

1200 87396 84303   0 11:25AM ??         0:00.01 bash --noprofile --norc -c e2e --help | col -bx

1200 87397 87396   0 11:25AM ??         0:01.17 /bin/bash /Users/someuser/bin/e2e --help


1200   108 87397   0 11:40AM ??         0:00.00 /bin/bash /Users/someuser/bin/e2e --help

1200   114   108   0 11:40AM ??         0:00.15 docker run --rm -v /tmp:/data someimage:someversion -u --help

My questions are

What could I have done that would cause VSC to repeatedy run a script which I was not working on.
How can VSC just run a script in the background without my knowlege?
How could I further debug to find out the root cause of this? I still don't know how the action was triggered, just that it was VSC triggering it.

Many thanks for any feedback you may have for me.
I wasn't trying anything. I was working on a bash script and while I was in VSC it was spawning docker containers in the background.

Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the Help: About command (run in the command palette) into your question post. Does this happen when you reload VS Code with extensions disabled (use the Developer: Reload With Extensions Disabled command in the command palette)? If not, then do an extension bisect to figure out what extension is causing it.

Hi @starball, I am running version 1.90.0. The first thing I did was remove extensions to be sure it would not happen again. I didn't need them in any case, I use VSC for bash and python. So I removed k8s and docker extensions as well as some golang extensions I do not need. I can't reproduce the error but if it happens again I will come back to this thread.
